# Copying nvmap-defined keybindings to emacs-state using a different prefix key

Tags: key-bindings, evil, keymap

I use general.el to define keybindings. For evil-mode, I've use nvmap, using something like the following:

```lisp
(nvmap :keymaps 'override :prefix "SPC" :global-prefix "M-SPC"
       "SPC"    '(counsel-M-x :which-key "M-x")
       "."      '(counsel-find-file :which-key "find-file")
       "u"      'universal-argument
        .
        .
        .
```

I would like to have these same keybindings when I'm in emacs-state, except using the `M-SPC` prefix. Is there a way to do this without simply copying and pasting all of these bindings?